# ASP.NET loses jquery bindings after postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have asp.net page where I bind in markup js file.
Js file working with set of functions mostly by class name. 
In these functions I get data from server using WCF and only change contols state and data.
Also onto the page I do postback. Everything is fine but my jquery functions don't work after that. After postback I only add a row to grid which is not involved in jquery logic.

But when I changed my logic from

> $(document).ready(function ()
>
> ```
> $jq("#ctrlID").change(function () {    }); )
> ```

to

> $(document).ready(function ()
>
> ```
> $jq("#ctrlID").live('change', function () {    }); )
> ```

everything works fine.

I'm puzzled. What it is? I don't add controls

Answer (score 2):

$(document).ready() executes when DOM is ready. However, it will not fire on ajax async postbacks, so all of your bindings are lost. Live() essentially keeps your bindings 'active' at all times. Another solution would be to use pageLoad() client side event, which is part of the ASP.NET client framework. This method would fire on normal and partial postbacks and you can bind your events there just like you would normally.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
// Your event bindings here
}
```

You can also use `args.get_isPartialLoad()` to determine if you're in a postback or an async postback.